# Magento, my cart, subtotal

Tags: magento, cart, subtotal

My cart shows wrong subtotal and I think this is als oaffecting calculation of tax (20%)in the Shoppin Cart and in the Checkout (prices here are correct but Subtotal, and total, have no 20% Vat tax)
Any idea what could be the problem?

new user.. i can't post images

Comment: is Mage_Tax enabled in your configuration.

Comment: Look at _System_ -> _Configuration_ -> _Sales(group)_ -> _Tax(tab)_  settings. And more precisely at _Shopping Cart Display Settings_ section. Make sure that everything is OK there.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php 

$subTotal = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal();

$totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getTotals();?>
 Total Items in Cart: <?php $totalItems = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsCount();  
                if($totalItems == 0){echo "0";}else{echo $totalItems;}?>
  Subtotal: $ <strong><?php $subTotal = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal(); echo number_format($subTotal,2); ?>
 <?php  if(isset($totals['tax']) && $totals['tax']->getValue()) {
  echo 'Tax: '.strip_tags(Mage::helper('core')->currency(number_format($totals['tax']->getValue(),2))); //Tax value if present
} ?>
<?php if(isset($totals['discount']) && $totals['discount']->getValue()) {
    echo 'Discount: '.strip_tags(Mage::helper('core')->currency(number_format($totals['discount']->getValue(),2))); //Discount value if applied
} ?>
<?php if(isset($order->getShippingAmount)){
echo 'Shipping Charges:'.strip_tags(Mage::helper('core')->currency(number_format($order->getShippingAmount,2)));
}?>
 Grand Total: $<?php $grandTotal = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal(); echo number_format($grandTotal,2); ?>
```

Please use this code, it will be show all cart info.